# Python import при использовании ipdb

Tags: python, python-import, ipython

Есть следующая файловая структура.

```
/home/myusername/python/
│
├── new_proj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script.py
│
├── oth_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── script.py
│
└── __init__.py
```

Если в скрипте, находящемся в директории `new_proj` попытаться импортировать что-то из `oth_project` следующим образом (без внесения дополнительных путей в `sys.path`):

```
from python.oth_project import script
```

То, ожидаемо, ошибка:

```
ImportError: No module named 'python'
```

Теперь, если перед импортированием своего модуля выполнить

```
import ipdb
```

то импортирование выполняется.

В `sys.path` добавляются только следующие пути:

```
'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/home/myusername/.ipython'
```

Так вот, интересует вопрос, `ipython` изменяет механизм импортирования не только в своем интерактивном режиме? И можно ли положиться на работоспособность такого импорта на будущее?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите импортировать как `from ..python.oth_project import script` (две точки  после `from`)?

Comment: Во-первых, это `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`. Во-вторых, хотел узнать, что именно меняет импорт `ipdb`.

Comment: Про первое — если это python3.5 то, как я понимаю, так быть не должно. Второе, возможно, достовернее всего по коду `ipdb` глянуть.